# sqlite: error when using another sqlite command inside a custom function (sqlite3.Connection.create_function)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm learning to create custom `sqlite3` functions in Python. This is my code:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
c = conn.cursor()


query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names (ID INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT)"
c.execute(query)


query = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('foo')"
c.execute(query)

query = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('boo')"
c.execute(query)

conn.commit()


def get_ID(name):
    
    query = "SELECT ID FROM names WHERE name = '{}'".format(name)
    c.execute(query)
    id = c.fetchall()
    print(id)
    return id

print(get_ID("foo"))

conn.create_function("GETID", 1, get_ID)

query = "SELECT GETID(?)"
c.execute(query, ("foo",))
print(c.fetchall())

c.close()
conn.close()
```

This is the ouptut:

```
[(1,)]
[(1,)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    c.execute(query, ("foo",))
sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception
```

Why does my function give an error?

Comment: You can use try-except to catch the exception in `get_ID` and in the except-block assign `traceback.format_exc()` to a global variable and return a simple value like `1`. After the query was executed, you can print the global variable to see the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different local cursor inside the function to execute the `SELECT` statement.
Also, `fetchall()` returns a list of sublists (a list of all the rows that are returned by the query) and not a scalar value.
Instead, take the `ID` with `fetchone()[0]`.
Finally, be consistent about the way that you pass the parameters to any query, better (my opinion) with `?` placeholders:

```
def get_ID(name):
    query = "SELECT ID FROM names WHERE name = ?"
    local_cursor = conn.cursor()
    local_cursor.execute(query, (name,))
    id = None
    if local_cursor.rowcount > 0:
        id = local_cursor.fetchone()[0]
    local_cursor.close()
    print(id)
    return id
```

Comment: To clarify, does the function require to return an sqlite data type? Another issue I found is what happens when two different `ID` have the same `name`. How it could return all?

Comment: @AbelGutiérrez the data type is not a problem for a numeric id in SQLite. Either numeric or a string it will work. The function as I've written it in my answer with `fetchone()` returns the first id with that specific name. If there may exist more than 1 ids with the same name and you want all of them in such a way that can be returned by a SQLite function then you can change the function's query to: `"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID) FROM names WHERE name = ?"` This will return all the ids as a comma separated string.

Comment: If I change `return id` to `return [id]` the program crashes, that is want I meant: does the python function need to return a sqlite data type, like an int? Besides that, if I simply change the query to `SELECT GETID(ID) FROM names WHERE name = ?`, I get an error (`sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception`).

Comment: Second question solved (multiple names)

Comment: @AbelGutiérrez why would you change `return id` to `return [id]`? The returned value of the function should be one of the 3 data types that SQLite accepts: numeric (integer or real), string or binary data (BLOB for SQLite). `[id]` is a Python data structure not valid in SQLite. For `SELECT GETID(ID) FROM names WHERE name = ?` I don't see the point because `GETID()` is defined to take as parameter a name and not an id. But the error is thrown because the query does not return rows and this is something that must be corrected. Check my edited function.

Comment: That question comes from my code where I have `fecthall` (a list). I didn't want to implement `return [id]` and I know now how to make the function works. Thanks!